# Access infromation of grandparent component from grandchild component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component in Vue called `RecipeView`, and it is an inline-component. inside it, i have these components: 
`comments`. and inside comments, i have `comment` and `NewCommentForm`, has it shows in the picture below.

[image]

I am passing in the `RecipeView` component the id as a prop, and would like to access it in the `NewCommentForm` component in order to set an endpoint that i will post to and save the comment.

This is the RecipeView component:

```html
<recipe-view :id="{{$recipe->id}}">

  <comments :data="{{$recipe->comment}}"@added="commentsCount++"></comments>

</recipe-view>
```

and the script for it is this:

```html
<script>
    import Comments from '../components/Comments.vue';
    export default {
        props: ['initialCommentsCount','id'],
        components: {Comments},

        data(){
            return {
                commentsCount: this.initialCommentsCount,
                recipe_id:this.id
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

The comments component looks like this:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="comment in items">
        <comment :data="comment"></comment>
    </div>
    <new-comment-form :endpoint="'/comments/**Here should go the id from parent RecipeView component**'" @created="add"></new-comment-form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import Comment from './Comment.vue';
    import NewCommentForm from './NewCommentForm.vue';
    export default {
        props: ['data'],

        components: {Comment, NewCommentForm},

        data() {
            return {
                items: this.data,
                endpoint: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            add(comment) {
                this.items.push(comment);
                this.$emit('added');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is the NewCommentForm component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <input class="input"
                           type = "text"
                           name="name"
                           placeholder="What is your name?"
                           required
                           v-model="name">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <textarea class="textarea"
                              name="body"
                              placeholder="Have your say here..."
                              required
                              v-model="body">

                    </textarea>
                </p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit"
                    @click="addComment"
                    class="button is-medium is-success">send</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['endpoint'],
        data(){
            return {
                body:'',
                name:'',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            addComment(){
                axios.post(this.endpoint, {
                    body:this.body,
                    name: this.name
                }).then(({data}) => {
                    this.body = '';
                    this.name = '';
                    this.$emit('created', data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to pass the value as a prop all the way down. `Comments` and `NewCommentForm` need to have the prop. `RecipeView` should pass it to `Comments` and `Comments` should pass it to `NewCommentForm`

Comment: @kmc059000 Can you tell me how to pass it from comments to the form?

Comment: Might be worth looking into some sort of state management here. It's getting messy when you're having to add props on multiple levels to chain one value. [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) is good but might be overkill for your app. Should be easy to knock something simple up though (You can use Vue.bus)

Comment: I have solved the problem. Instead of getting it from parent component, i just gave it directly to comments, and from there it was a regular thing. sometimes i just love inline templates :) Thanks alot.